# Calculating a new date value from dynamically created div values

Tags: jquery

I have two divs: one with a custom friendly date output and one with a number (both these values are created dynamically)

How can I create a sum of these to output a new date value with jquery?

For example:

```
 <div class="date"> 13 jun </div>
 <div class="value"> +10 </div>
 <div class="new-date"> in here </div>
```

Output I am looking for would be:

```
 <div class="date"> 13 jun </div>
 <div class="value"> +10 </div>
 <div class="new-date"> 23 jun </div>
```

Comment: Without a year February would be problematic.  Lots of hits for *dd mmm yyyy to date* and *add days to date* if you search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just need to write a function to add days.  However, you should include the year in your date, so instead of just 13 jun, you would add 13 jun 2017 or something like that.

```
function addDays(date, days) {
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    return result;
}
```

So you would pass in "13 jun" and "10" for example and it will output the new result you are looking for.

See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/nLonjus1/

You would just need to specify the new-date div like so:

```
$('.new-date').val(newDate);
```

Comment: Thanks Jack - viewing that I get an invalid date alert, could you show how to output this into the new-date div also instead of an alert?

Comment: Still getting same - invalid date alert

Comment: show me the code you're using.   make sure there's no spaces around 13 jun

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/joely27/vwbcm7qd/ - trying to pass in the values from the divs by finding them dynamically

Comment: The way you get your date and days with jquery is to use  $('.date').val(); and $('.days').val();

Comment: Bit confused, because the value in the above div 'value' is dynamic so I cant directly include it in my script. Trying to basically for addDays create a calculation that adds value of div class value to date of div class date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146561/discussion-between-jack-marchetti-and-joelyorca).

Comment: Thanks jack -  you've been very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var date = $('.date').html();

//The number "10" can be changed as you need
var newDate = new Date(date) + 10;

$('.new-value').html(newDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, How can I implement this into my markup, so the date would show in my div: new-date